# faster way to make new variables containing data frames to be rbinded

Tags: r, dplyr, partitioning, paste, magrittr

I want to make a bunch of new variables a,b,c,d.....z to store tibble data frames. I will then rbind the new variables that store tibble data frames and export them as a csv. How do I do this faster without having to specify the new variables each time?

```
a<- subset(data.frame, variable1="condition1",....,) %>% group_by() %>% summarize( a=mean())
b<-subset(data.frame, variable1="condition2",....,) %>% group_by() %>% summarize( a=mean())
....

z<-subset(data.frame, variable1="condition2",....,) %>% group_by() %>% summarize( a=mean())

rbind(a,b,....,z)
```

There's got to be a faster way to do this. My data set is large so having it stored in memory as partitions of a,b,c,....z is causing the computer to crash. Typing the subset conditions to form the partitions repeatedly is tedious.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `subset` doesn't have an argument `variable1`

Comment: `lapply` or some type of loop would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple objects in the global environemnt, rread them in a `list`, and bind it

```
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

It would be much faster with `fread` than in any other option

---

If we are using strings to be passed onto `group_by`, convert the string to symbol with `sym` from `rlang` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(c("condition1", "condition2"), c("a", "b") ~ df1 %>%
                      group_by(!! rlang::sym(.x)) %>%
                      summarise(!! .y := mean(colname)))
```

If the 'condition1', 'condition2' etc are expressions, place it as `quosure` and evaluate it

```
map2_df(quos(condition1, condition2), c("a", "b"), ~ df1 %>%
                 filter(!! .x) %>%
                  summarise(!! .y := mean(colnames)))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
conditions <- quos(Petal.Length>1.5,Species == 'setosa',Sepal.Length > 5) 
map2(conditions, c('a', 'b', 'c'), ~ 
           iris %>% 
                filter(!! .x)  %>%
                summarise(!! .y := mean(Sepal.Length)))
#[[1]]
#         a
#1 6.124779

#[[2]]
#      b
#1 5.006

#[[3]]
#         c
#1 6.129661
```

It would be a 3 column dataset if we use `map2_dfc`

NOTE: It is not clear whether the OP meant 'condition1', 'condition2' as expressions to be passed on for `filter`ing the rows or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using `purrr` package:

You may need to use NSE depends on what's your condition. You can reference [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

```r
purrr::map_df(
    c("condition1","condition2",..., "conditionn"), 
    # .x for each condition
    ~ subset(your_data_frame, variable1=.x,....,) %>% group_by(some_columns) %>% summarise(a = mean(some_columns))
)
```

Example using iris:

```r
library(rlang)
conditions <- c("Petal.Length>1.5","Species == 'setosa'","Sepal.Length > 5")
map(conditions, function(x){
    iris %>% 
        dplyr::filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(x)) %>%
        head()
})
```

Example using `iris`:

```r
conditions <- c("Petal.Length>1.5","Species == 'setosa'","Sepal.Length > 5")
map(conditions, ~ iris %>% dplyr::filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(.x)) %>% nrow())
# or (!! is almost equivalent to eval or rlang::eval_tidy())
map(conditions, ~ iris %>% dplyr::filter(eval(rlang::parse_expr(.x))) %>% nrow())
```

```r
[[1]]
[1] 113

[[2]]
[1] 50

[[3]]
[1] 118
```

Comment: @yifan Every new variable I plan to make is a subset of the data_frame based on a different condition. Recalling my original plan to make variables a,....,z, is condition 1 for variable a, condition 2 for variable b,,, condition n for variable z? Condition 1,.... Condition n are boolean conditions, do I separate condition 1,,,,.n by commas within the concatenation "c"

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate them using `c`. You you need to evaluate string as expression using `!!` and `parse_expression.`